# Stream an opencv video over RTSP

Tags: opencv, rtsp

Does anyone know a link where I can catch RTSP stream to test video capture with rtsp video source? I have tried it with usb cam and with webcam, but I want to test it with RTSP stream.

Here is the source:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap("rtsp:\\ANYTHING,PLEASE"); // open the video file for reading

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
         return -1;
    }

    //cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 300); //start the video at 300ms

    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video

     cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
                        cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
                       break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
                cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
                break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate a RTSP stream with Videolan VLC.
Media / Stream / Add any video file / Stream / RTSP Add / Port and path / Video H.264 + MP3 (MP4) / Stream.
Then you obtain a video streaming with something like rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/vid. Of course you can read that stream using VLC or OpenCV.
dAAvid

Comment: Tnx, tried that some time ago and it works ok. I've managed to convert http stream into rtsp with VLC